# Генератор всех строк с n заменами

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Как написать генератор, который принимает на вход строку, допустим `abc` и параметр `n` допустим `n=1` и последовательно выдает все строки, которые получаются из этой заменой в `n` символов?

Для примера выше `abc` и алфавита `abc` с `n=1`, получаем такие строки:
`bbc`, `cbc`, `aac`, `acc`, `aba`, `abb`.

P.S. Алфавит должен заранее задаваться в теле генератора, либо передаваться как параметр.

Comment: какой результат должен быть для n = 2?

Comment: `{'aaa',
 'aab',
 'aac',
 'aba',
 'abb',
 'abc',
 'aca',
 'acb',
 'acc',
 'bac',
 'bba',
 'bbb',
 'bbc',
 'bcc',
 'cac',
 'cba',
 'cbb',
 'cbc',
 'ccc'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вроде работает:

```
import itertools as it

def repl(text, alphabet='abc', n=1):
    swaps = list(it.combinations_with_replacement(range(len(text)), n))
    for letter in alphabet:
        for swap in swaps:
            text_copy = list(text)
            for idx in swap:
                text_copy[idx] = letter
            yield ''.join(text_copy)

for r in repl('AAA', alphabet='agct'):
    print(r, end=' ')
```

**Вывод**:

```
AAA AAA AAA GAA AGA AAG CAA ACA AAC TAA ATA AAT
```

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов исправил код

Comment: Ага, сейчас работает, единственное, что у меня строки должны быть уникальные при выводе, но в принципе это через set легко допилить.

Answer (score 2):

Для `n=1` (и, скорее всего, для строки с неповторяющимися символами):

```
a = "abc"
alphabet="abc"
print(*(a.replace(x,y) for x in alphabet for y in a if x!=y))
```

> bbc cbc aac acc aba abb

Answer (score 1):

вариант для `n = 1`

```
abc = 'abc'

def test(textl):
    text = list(text)
    arr = []
    
    for i in range(len(text)):
        for j in range(len(abc)):
            if text[i] != abc[j]:
                arr.append(text.copy())
                arr[-1][i] = abc[j]
    return arr
```